# C++ cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. Could you pls help me get rid of the errors:

error C2259: 'MinHeap' : cannot instantiate abstract class

IntelliSense: return type is not identical to nor covariant with return type "const int &" of overridden virtual function function

```
template <class T> class DataStructure { 
    public:
        virtual ~DataStructure () {}

        virtual bool IsEmpty () const = 0;    

        virtual void Push(const T&) = 0;

        virtual const T& Top() const = 0;

        virtual void Pop () = 0;
};

class MinHeap : public DataStructure<int>
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> A;       

    public:
        bool IsEmpty() const
        {
            ..
        }

        int Top() const
        {
           ..         
        }

        void Push(int item)
        {
            ...
        }

        void Pop()
        {
            ..
        }   
};
```

Comment: Do `Top` And `Push` match the base? (No.) Should you use `std::priority_queue`? (Yes.)

Comment: I suppose this needs a `homework` tag? Otherwise the advice would be "don't implement that yourself".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with `const T& Top()` vs. `int Top()`. The latter is different from the former, and thus not an override. Instead it *hides* the base class function. You need to return exactly the same as in the base class version: `const int& Top() const`.
The same problem exists for `Push()`, BTW.

Comment: And `void Push(int item)` should be `void Push(const int& item)`

Comment: @Charles: I was just adding this. `:)`

Comment: In industrial-strength C++, you'd actually want something like `return_type<T>::type Top() const`, where `return_type<T>::type` is generally `T const&` but `return_type<int>::type` is just plain `int`.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
class MinHeap : public DataStructure<int>
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> A;       

    public:
        bool IsEmpty() const
        {
            ..
        }

        const int& Top() const
        {
           ..         
        }

        void Push(const int& item)
        {
            ...
        }

        void Pop()
        {
            ..
        }   
};
```

Note that it is using `const int&` instead of `int` for Top and Push

Answer (score 0):

*(The errors are due to a **signature mismatch** in function `Push` and in function `Top`)*

--

**Modern C++**

C++11 adds two inheritance control keywords: `override` and `final`. It is advisable to use either the override or final specifier when declaring an overridden function. Two common issues associated with overriding virtual functions are: **Inadvertent overriding** and **Signature mismatch** (Your case).

*`override` ensures that an overriding virtual function declared in a derived class has the same signature as that of the base class*. `final` blocks further overriding of a virtual function and further derivation of a class.

Example:

```cpp
#include <vector>


template <class T> 
class DataStructure 
{
public:
    virtual ~DataStructure() = default;

    virtual bool IsEmpty() const = 0;
    virtual void Push(const T&) = 0;
    virtual const T& Top() const = 0;
    virtual void Pop() = 0;
};


class MinHeap final : public DataStructure<int> // <--
{
private:
    std::vector<int> a_;

public:
    bool IsEmpty() const override // <--
    {
        // Do something 
        return true;
    }

    void Push(const int& item) override // <-- (Signature mismatch fixed)
    {
        // Do something 
    }

    const int& Top() const override // <-- (Signature mismatch fixed)
    {
        // Do something 
        return 0;
    }

    void Pop() override // <--
    {
        // Do something         
    }
};
```