# Overwrite Base Class Member with New Type

Tags: c++, derived-class, return-type, base-class

I'm trying to use C++ to emulate something like dynamic typing. I'm approaching the problem with inherited classes. For example, a function could be defined as

```
BaseClass* myFunction(int what) {
    if (what == 1) {
        return new DerivedClass1();
    } else if (what == 2) {
        return new DerivedClass2();
    }
}
```

The base class and each derived class would have the same members, but of different types. For example, `BaseClass` may have `int xyz = 0` (denoting nothing), `DerivedClass1` might have `double xyz = 123.456`, and `DerivedClass2` might have `bool xyz = true`. Then, I could create functions that returned one type but in reality returned several different types. The problem is, when ere I try to do this, I always access the base class's version of `xyz`. I've tried using pointers (`void*` for the base, and "correct" ones for the derived classes), but then every time I want to access the member, I have to do something like `*(double*)(obj->xyz)` which ends up being very messy and unreadable.

Here's an outline of my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {};

    void* member;
};

class Bar : public Foo {

public:
    Bar() {
        member = new double(123.456); // Make member a double
    };

};

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    Foo* obj = new Bar;

    cout << *(double*)(obj->member);

    return 0;
};
```

I guess what I'm trying to ask is, **is this "good" coding practice? If not, is there a different approach to functions that return multiple types or accept multiple types?**

Comment: I'd prefer using templates for such, instead of a `void*`

Comment: Please expand...? In what way should I use templates?

Comment: In the base class, that declares the `member`.

Comment: And then derive the derived classes from different templates? Wouldn't that make them different types (C++ treats `BaseClass<int>` as an unrelated class to `BaseClass<double>`, I believe)?

Comment: Yes, that would be the consequence. But I think you could also just provide a templated member function that at least wraps the cast from the `void*` (along with some static checks may be) instead of making the whole class a template.

Comment: You mean create a function to retrieve the value with something like `return *(T*)member`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Clients need to know the correct type specialization anyway. I've done such designs, unfortunately for work, and I can't give you that code sample. I'm looking forward to find another one for you.

Comment: Here's one sample that comes pretty close to what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750200/c-cannot-instantiate-abstract-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not actually the way to do it.

There are two typical ways to implement something akin to dynamic typing in C++:

- the Object-Oriented way: a class hierarchy and the `Visitor` pattern
- the Functional-Programming way: a tagged union

The latter is rather simple using `boost::variant`, the former is well documented on the web. I would personally recommend `boost::variant` to start with.

If you want to go down the full dynamic typing road, then things get trickier. In dynamic typing, an object is generally represented as a dictionary containing both other objects and functions, and a function takes a list/dictionary of objects and returns a list/dictionary of objects. Modelling it in C++ is feasible, but it'll be wordy...

---

> How is an object represented in a dynamically typed language ?

The more generic representation is for the language to represent an object as both a set of values (usually named) and a set of methods (named as well). A simplified representation looks like:

```
struct Object {
    using ObjectPtr = std::shared_ptr<Object>;
    using ObjectList = std::vector<ObjectPtr>;
    using Method = std::function<ObjectList(ObjectList const&)>;

    std::map<std::string, ObjectPtr> values;
    std::map<std::string, Method> methods;
};
```

If we take Python as an example, we realize we are missing a couple things:

1. We cannot implement `getattr` for example, because `ObjectPtr` is a different type from `Method`
2. This is a recursive implementation, but without the *basis*: we are lacking innate types (typically `Bool`, `Integer`, `String`, ...)

Dealing with the first issue is relatively easy, we transform our object to be able to become *callable*:

```
class Object {
public:
    using ObjectPtr = std::shared_ptr<Object>;
    using ObjectList = std::vector<ObjectPtr>;
    using Method = std::function<ObjectList(ObjectList const&)>;

    virtual ~Object() {}

    //
    // Attributes
    //
    virtual bool hasattr(std::string const& name) {
        throw std::runtime_error("hasattr not implemented");
    }

    virtual ObjectPtr getattr(std::string const&) {
        throw std::runtime_error("gettattr not implemented");
    }

    virtual void setattr(std::string const&, ObjectPtr) {
        throw std::runtime_error("settattr not implemented");
    }

    //
    // Callable
    //
    virtual ObjectList call(ObjectList const&) {
        throw std::runtime_error("call not implemented");
    }

    virtual void setcall(Method) {
        throw std::runtime_error("setcall not implemented");
    }
}; // class Object

class GenericObject: public Object {
public:
    //
    // Attributes
    //
    virtual bool hasattr(std::string const& name) override {
        return values.count(name) > 0;
    }

    virtual ObjectPtr getattr(std::string const& name) override {
        auto const it = values.find(name);
        if (it == values.end) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Unknown attribute");
        }

        return it->second;
    }

    virtual void setattr(std::string const& name, ObjectPtr object) override {
        values[name] = std::move(object);
    }

    //
    // Callable
    //
    virtual ObjectList call(ObjectList const& arguments) override {
        if (not method) { throw std::runtime_error("call not implemented"); }
        return method(arguments);
    }

    virtual void setcall(Method m) {
        method = std::move(m);
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, ObjectPtr> values;
    Method method;
}; // class GenericObject
```

And dealing with the second issue requires seeding the recursion:

```
class BoolObject final: public Object {
public:
    static BoolObject const True = BoolObject{true};
    static BoolObject const False = BoolObject{false};

    bool value;
}; // class BoolObject

class IntegerObject final: public Object {
public:
    int value;
}; // class IntegerObject

class StringObject final: public Object {
public:
    std::string value;
}; // class StringObject
```

And now you need to add capabilities, such as value comparison.

Comment: Since using Boost isn't an option, can you please expand on how you're speaking of dictionaries/lists? Can't a dictionary or list only hold one type of object? Which brings me back to the original question...

Comment: I included the necessary headers, but when I compile, I get this: http://pastebin.com/tRHihqkE (using GCC. Clang gives similar errors)

Comment: @CalebP: I am using the C++11 notation here, in C++98 you would write `typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;` instead. You can activate C++11 with the `-std=c++11` flag if I remember correctly.

Comment: With which compiler? Clang or GCC?

Comment: Log for Clang with -std=c++11 enabled: http://pastebin.com/Zius2tbs (clang -v outputs `Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)`)

Comment: @CalebP: both Clang and gcc :), you will need the include `<memory>` for `std::shared_ptr` (if it's available in your distribution, looks kinda old), otherwise you can use `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following design:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {};
    virtual T& member() = 0;
};

class Bar : public Foo<double> {

public:
    Bar() : member_(123.456) {
    };

    virtual double& member() { return member_; }    
private:
    double member_;
};

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    Foo<double>* obj = new Bar;

    cout << obj->member();

    return 0;
};
```

But as a consequence the `Foo` class already needs to be specialized and isn't a container for ***any*** type anymore.
Other ways to do so, are e.g. using a [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html) in the base class

Answer (score 0):

If you need a dynamic solution you should stick to using `void*` and size or `boost::any`. Also you need to pass around some type information as integer code or string so that you can decode the actual type of the content.
See also *property design pattern*.
For example, you can have a look at zeromq socket options https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/src/options.cpp

Comment: Property design pattern? Do you have a less generic name for it? Googling doesn't show anything.